# python3.6 ssl erro

Tags: python, ssl

In Ubuntu 16.04, I use python3.6 ( pip 9.0.1) to install BeautifulSoup but failed. The error is:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL , however the ssl module in Python is not available. 
could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org
```

Secondly, Ubuntu 16.04 ships with the built-in python2.7, but I want to learn Python 3.6. So I load it and use that order:

```
./configure
make && make install
```

The result is the python 3.5 was installed in the `PATH`, and BeautifulSoup was installed. I use `make altinstall` to complete the Python 3.6 installing. It's so wondering.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please click on **Edit** and add details of what exactly you are asking here.

Comment: sorry, i want to know how to install BeautifulSoup in python3.6 even though i installed the module in python3.5

Comment: and the error is about ssl when i use pip install BeatifulSoup

Comment: This is a reasonable question.  https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4205 identifes this as a bug with pip on python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

Before `./configure` you need install all requirements.

In your case, not enough `libssl-dev` library.

To install it using `apt` do this:

`# apt install libssl-dev`